# Editing some files within VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two text files, `C:\Test1.txt` and `C:\Test2.txt`.

`C:\Test1.txt` data consists of a column separated by a space (" "):

```
Data Data
Data Data
Data Data
```

`C:\Test2.txt` data consists of:

```
Data
Data
Data
```

The fields in Test2 Column 1 are the fields in Column 1 Test1. I'm trying add the matching fields from Test1. So for example:

C:\Test1.txt

```
Mercedez Silver
Bentley Black
Audi Blue
BMW White
Honda Gold
```

C:\Test2.txt

```
BMW
Mercedez
Bentley
Audi
Honda
```

After I have run the code:

C:\Test2.txt

```
BMW White
Mercedez Silver
Bentley Black
Audi Blue
Honda Gold
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just want to find all cars in in txt2 that are also in txt1 and overwrite the lines in txt2 from txt1. Then this should work:

```
Dim l1Infos = From l1 In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test1.txt")
              Select New With {.Line = l1, .Tokens = l1.Split(" "c)}
Dim result = From l1 In l1Infos
             Join l2 In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test2.txt")
             On l1.Tokens(0) Equals l2
             Select l1.Line
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Test2.txt", result)
```

Note that it`s yet not safe for exceptional data.

Comment: Hi, no it is not homework.  Sorry but how do i post what i have coded so far? I'm struggling :(

Comment: Tim, that coding is looking good.  Would it be difficult to 1)ignore any blank lines, 2) if the car is not found in the other text file then leave it blank?

Comment: @user1413746: What should be difficult? If you're using at least .NET 3.5 you could copy/paste it. As i've already mentioned, it's yet not safe if your files for example contain more white-spaces. But it should give you an idea anyway. Basically it's overwriting all lines in file 2 with the matching lines from file 1(according to the car).

Answer (score 0):

So your task in technical terms is this (according to the original question and comments):

- Assume the first file is a dictionary of car make to color.
- Assume the second file is a list of makes.
- You need to find a match for those makes, using the first file.
- Ignore empty lines in both input files.
- If make is not found, put an empty string as a color.

An old school solution for this can be split into 3 parts:

```
'read the first file into a dictionary of make to color
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test1.txt")
  Dim a() As String = line.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  If a.Length = 0 Then Continue For 'ignore blank lines
  Dim key As String = a(0)
  Dim value As String = a(1)
  dict.Add(key, value)
Next

'find matches for makes listed in the second file and prepare output
Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)
For Each key As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test2.txt")
  If key = String.Empty Then Continue For 'ignore blank lines
  Dim value As String = Nothing
  dict.TryGetValue(key, value) 'leave Color blank if not found
  outputLines.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", key, value))
Next

'write output
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Test3.txt", outputLines)
```

Built for extensibility, the above can be easily tuned further for your needs. Note here that I am outputting to another file (#3). This is to preserve input for testing purposes. You want to preserve input in case something goes wrong, and you need to quick fix & rerun the program. You can change the code to replace file #2 after you are sure it works as expected.